# How to handel php error

Tags: php, html

I'm using two files one is of html and another is of php 
In my html file I have created this

code for my html file : index.html

```
<html>
<body>
<form method='get' action='ans.php'
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="button" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When user enter the input into the input tag it will take the user to the ans.php file in which I have coded some php

My php file: ans.php

```
<?php

$text= $_GET['name'];
echo $text
?>
```

Comment: use isset of php to check variable is set or not

Comment: how will user go directly to `ans.php` without `submit`

Comment: I said that the file is perfectly working I want only that how to handel the error I have only shown the demo of my html and php file

Comment: This will help you http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(isset($_GET['name']))
{
 echo $_GET['name']; 
}
else 
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `empty()` to check if the variable is `present` and `not empty` or `false`. Add a check -

```
if(!empty($_GET['name'])){
   $text= $_GET['name'];
   echo $text;
}
```

If the `variable` may contain `false` then Hanky 웃 Panky's answer will work.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky missed that 1.